# How to make sure no one can withdraw Ether from your smart contract?

Tags: solidity, ether, ico, tokens

I'm playing around with Solidity and now I'm coding my own "ICO".
Followed this tutorial:

> [How to build your own Ethereum based ERC20 Token and launch an ICO
>
>   in next 20 minutes](https://hashnode.com/post/how-to-build-your-own-ethereum-based-erc20-token-and-launch-an-ico-in-next-20-minutes-cjbcpwzec01c93awtbij90uzn)

and things worked fine. But I've seen a lot of articles online how a smart contract is drained from a hacker or how funds are forever locked.

How to make sure only you can access the funds from your ICO?

Answer (score 2):

That is an outdated smart contract code without prevention of overflow. 
The PoWHCoin was exploited because of an overflow bug.
To prevent such from happening, you'll have to implement the Safemath library.
I'll advise you to make use of the latest Open Zeppelin source code on github.

Comment: yeah I read about that hack, thats why im being cautious and trying to understand it better. Does Open Zeppelin have a better code for ICOs?

Comment: Yes, you can check the open zeppelin library on github https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity